# Checking file permissions from R

Tags: r, user-permissions

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am looking for a way to check the file permissions in the current folder (the one that can be obtained using getwd()) in the R language. I am working on a Unix platform and know that I can get file permission mode using file.info(), but I do not know how to check to which category (owner / group / rest) I belong and thus what specific rights I have.

A second question that I have is whether this can also be done cross-platform, so that this would work also on other platforms (most importantly on Windows).

Thank you very much for you help!

Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file.access()` returns this information.  So

```
file.access(".", 2)
```

tells you whether or not you can write to the current working directory.  You can supply a vector of filenames/directories as appropriate.

Note that if there is a chance that permissions can change underneath you (i.e. multitasking system), you may be better off to just use `try` and catch the error if you don't have permissions.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your help, but as far as I am aware this won't tell you whether a user has reading/writing/executing rights (or am I wrong?) Also, I cannot find out which of the three categories (owner / group / rest) applies to the current user (if I would know that I could infer those rights from the permission 'mode'). Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Thanks a lot; I cannot believe that it is this simple (I have been searching the internet for quite a while). I changed your answer to file.access(".", 2) as this is most to the point I guess. Thanks again. Thomas

Comment: Sometimes these things are hard to track down.  Here's a link to the manual with some specific pointers to filesystem stuff: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operating-system-access

Comment: Please add a note that for some vague and ill-defined reason (not ascertainable to me), it returns `FALSE` (that is, 0,) for **success** and `-1` for **failure**. Why R doesn't just convert these numbers of sensible booleans is beyond me.